# Changing values automatically based on date

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-2.2

I have this object

```
public class Iteration
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

And it stores values like:

```
Id: 1
Start 10-07-2019
End 17-07-2019
Active: true
```

Here I set Iteration active if it is in the range, this is when creating a new iteration (POST request).

```
public async Task<ActionResult> AddIteration([FromBody]IterationDTO iterationDTO)
{
    // Set active if current date is in the added range
    if (DateTime.Now.Date >= iterationDTO.Start.Date && DateTime.Now.Date <= iterationDTO.End.Date)
    {
        iterationDTO.Active = true;
    }
    DB.Set<Iteration>().Add(iterationDTO);
    await DB.SaveChangesAsync();
    return Ok(iterationDTO);
}
```

Now the problem is with the field Active, I check it when creating a new iteration. But I want it to change automatically any time not just when creating, how can I do this? For example, day changes and there is a new check that changes the active iteration.

Comment: Is the intention to only have one active iteration?

Comment: @klabranche Yes. The iterations are not overlapping, so maximum of 1 iteration can be active at a time.

Comment: I honestly do not understand what your intention is. Exactly when and based on what do you want this field to change? And what do you mean with "change", perhaps updating it on the database?

Comment: @Janis - Then in that case, before you add a new iteration, do an update that sets Active = false for any Iteration records that are true.  For extra safety, do both in a transaction so if something goes wrong both fail to change.

Comment: Okay so I mean for example there are 2 Iteration objects one is from 10 July to 12 July and the second is from 13 July to 14 July. And today is 12 so the first iteration is Active. But when day changes to 13 July I want to update the records on database and make the second iteration Active. How do I do this automatically? So I don't have to send update request and do it manually.

Comment: @Janis - Oh.  Well, in this kind of case described you would need to have a scheduled task  that looks at the Iteration table and decides which iterations are active and which are not.  You can write a command line C# application that scheduled tasks run on a regular interval.  In your code above, it would also have to first query for Intervals that this would replace.  Inactivate those and then add.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you are complicating things with updating database entry since you can always compute that value from `start` and `end` properties.

You can just create extension on your model if you need to access it on backend

```
public static class IterationExtensions {
    public static bool Active(this Iteration iteration)
    {
        return DateTime.Now.Date >= iteration.Start.Date && DateTime.Now.Date <= iteration.End.Date;
    }
}
```

or just map it to ViewModel before sending it to client:

```
public class IterationViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
    public bool Active 
    { 
        get { return DateTime.Now.Date >= this.Start.Date && DateTime.Now.Date <= this.End.Date; } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you need here is a service that keep running and checking the iteration from time to time.

You could, for example, create a windows service that, for every 24 hours, validate the iteration and, if it is out of date, unactivate it. You will have to create a update method anyways.

Check this link for help:
https://stackify.com/creating-net-core-windows-services/